# Can we get Stock adjusted price for Indian share market using Quandl library in python?

Tags: python, quandl

I am trying to use Quandl library in python to get the stock price of HDFC Bank for last three years. But I observed that it does not give stock adjusted price after the stock split.
Is there any way to get the adjusted price because the regular price will be misleading for any data science use case.

I am using the below code to extract the data.

```
import quandl
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'APIKey'
HDFC = quandl.get('BSE/BOM500180', start_date='2017-01-01', end_date=today)
HDFC= HDFC.reset_index()
print (HDFC)
```

Here is the screenshot of the chart. If you observe here, there was a stock split on 19th Sept'19. So any prediction will be misleading if I use this data.

[image]

Comment: I would think implementing an offset at that point in time manually is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using quandl, I am now using yahoo finance. That has stock adjusted price